# Searchbox in android

Tags: android, search

I need to create application in which one textview are there to search any content from   Database.

So can you guide me that how can I do that?

Comment: i am little confuse that how can i do this?there is no stuck or problem.

Comment: This is not a place to come and ask for somebody to do the work for you.

Comment: sorry sir! but can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you are already knowing that you have to have database and textview, then why dont you try? Once you get stuck anywhere then post code and stack trace if possible.

Comment: see paresh , i have database,& i can get result as per enter editable textbox in textview,but problem is that it search by whole content only,where i want sensitive search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very simple you can get idea from the following links
[Cursors](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/)
[SqLite](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_the_sqlite-database_-_cursors-t319.html) 
[SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)
if still getting problem in coding then post your code but first you have to try for it